How do i get more information on memory usage using benchmarking, specifically, the memory column from bench::mark function
I used the mark function from the bench package and I want to understand the memory results.
Ultimately I'm trying to find memory efficient code to calculate mean, variance, confidence variables on a dataset of tens of millions of rows long and usually 30 columns wide. I'm using benchmarking to test different approaches (including data.table vs dataframe/tibbles) and looking to understand and get more detailed information.
Here is some test code
# make function
row_sample_variance <- function(x, ...){
  n <- length(x)
  if (n <=1) {
    return(0)
  } else {
    rowSums((x- rowMeans(x, ...))^2, ...)/(length(x)-1)
  }
}

# make test data
test_data  <- matrix(runif(1000*30), nrow = 1000, ncol = 30)
test_data <- as.data.frame(test_data)

# Benchmerk
bench::mark(iterations = 4,
            check = F,
            "dplyr" = test_data %>% mutate(mean   = rowMeans(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T), 
                                     var    = row_sample_variance(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T), 
                                     SD     = sqrt(var), 
                                     "-95%" = mean -(1.96*SD), 
                                     "+95%" = mean +(1.96*SD), 
            ), 
            "Indvidual" = {
             rowMeans(test_data[, ColNum:length(test_data)], na.rm=T)
             row_sample_variance(test_data[, ColNum:length(test_data)], na.rm=T)
             sqrt(row_sample_variance(test_data[, ColNum:length(test_data)], na.rm=T)) 
             rowMeans(test_data[, ColNum:length(test_data)], na.rm=T) -(1.96*sqrt(row_sample_variance(test_data[, ColNum:length(test_data)], na.rm=T)))
             rowMeans(test_data[, ColNum:length(test_data)], na.rm=T) +(1.96*sqrt(row_sample_variance(test_data[, ColNum:length(test_data)], na.rm=T)))
            }, 
            
            "full dplyr" = test_data %>%  mutate(mean   = rowMeans(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T), 
                                                 var    = row_sample_variance(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T), 
                                                 SD     = sqrt(row_sample_variance(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T)), 
                                                 "-95%" = rowMeans(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T) -(1.96*sqrt(row_sample_variance(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T))), 
                                                 "+95%" = rowMeans(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T) +(1.96*sqrt(row_sample_variance(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T))), 
            )
            
)

I get the following results, and I'd like to know how to get more information from the memory column currently just shows <Rprofmem [231 X 3]>
results from bench::mark function

To answer my own question somewhat, I saved the output, and was then able to view the specific results of the memory column
results <- bench::mark(iterations = 4,
        check = F,
        "dplry" = test_data %>% mutate(mean   = rowMeans(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T), 
                                 var    = row_sample_variance(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T), 
                                 SD     = sqrt(var), 
                                 "-95%" = mean -(1.96*SD), 
                                 "+95%" = mean +(1.96*SD), 
        ), 
        "Indvidual" = {
         rowMeans(test_data[, ColNum:length(test_data)], na.rm=T)
         row_sample_variance(test_data[, ColNum:length(test_data)], na.rm=T)
         sqrt(row_sample_variance(test_data[, ColNum:length(test_data)], na.rm=T)) 
         rowMeans(test_data[, ColNum:length(test_data)], na.rm=T) -(1.96*sqrt(row_sample_variance(test_data[, ColNum:length(test_data)], na.rm=T)))
         rowMeans(test_data[, ColNum:length(test_data)], na.rm=T) +(1.96*sqrt(row_sample_variance(test_data[, ColNum:length(test_data)], na.rm=T)))
        }, 
        
        "full dplry" = test_data %>%  mutate(mean   = rowMeans(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T), 
                                             var    = row_sample_variance(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T), 
                                             SD     = sqrt(row_sample_variance(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T)), 
                                             "-95%" = rowMeans(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T) -(1.96*sqrt(row_sample_variance(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T))), 
                                             "+95%" = rowMeans(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T) +(1.96*sqrt(row_sample_variance(.[, ColNum:length(.)], na.rm=T))), 
        ))

view(results[[11]][1]

Where 11 is the memory column and 1 is the first row or dplyr result.
This gives you how much memory call/action the code is doing in bytes

You might also consider using terra  and see if you can ingest your file via rast(file_name, type = ""). Then looking at ?mem_info and terraOptions to be used in wopt(, expecially those related to memory (memfrac, memmin, memmax, todisk) and let terra work out the chunking for you, by calculation your doing .Without blowing up your session. 10^6 rows and i'm in restart. 5^6 rows, not in memory, things go pretty smoothly.
